# Meteor spectrogram from wave files

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, librosa, rtl-sdr

I am using [SpectrumLab](https://www.qsl.net/dl4yhf/spectra1.html) for logging meteors with an SDR. SpectrumLab records [waterfall](https://www.qsl.net/dl4yhf/speclab/specdisp.htm#waterfall) screenshots and a wav file of an event. I am trying to reproduce the waterfall screenshot of SpectrumLab from the wave file but the pattern looks different:

```
import librosa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import librosa.display
audio_data = 'event20230131_101027_26.wav'
x , sr = librosa.load(audio_data)
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5))
librosa.display.waveshow(x, sr=sr)

X = librosa.stft(x)
Xdb = librosa.amplitude_to_db(abs(X))
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5))
librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, sr=sr, x_axis='time', y_axis='log')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Screenshot of SpectrumLab:
[image]

Screenshot generated with librosa:
[image]

Wave file which was recorded together with the screenshot in SpectrumLab:

[Wavefile](https://github.com/snowformatics/sdr_scatter/blob/master/convert_wave/event20230131_101027_26.wav)

Comment: What exactly does the SpectrumLab screenshot show? I assume the y-axis is radio frequency, which is far different from the audio frequencies that you have in the wav file. It's not obvious how the SpectrumLab input is converted to a wav file, so it's worth looking into how that is performed before expecting to see the same output.

Comment: Yes,  y-axis is radio frequency.